# Regex. Split string depends on delimiter and include them

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my str example, I need to save delimiters near last word like dot, dash and space.

**str example:**

```
   a = 'Beautiful. is. better5-than ugly'
```

**what I tried**

```
re.split('\W+', a)
['Beautiful', 'is', 'better5', 'than', 'ugly']
```

**expected output:**

```
 ['Beautiful.', ' ', 'is.', ' ', 'better5-', 'than', ' ', 'ugly']
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What about space ? I don't see it in your "expected result"

Comment: yes inducing whitespace, i will  update

Comment: Do you know the types of delimiters (`-` or `.`) you have to work with or can they be anything?

Comment: The hard bit there is splitting at the dash and attaching it to the preceding element. Otherwise the pattern `re.split(r'(\S+)',a)` works one way and  `'([^\s-]+)'` otherwise.

Comment: You need to think more carefully about what your delimiters are.  Based on your desired output, I would say the empty string is your delimiter, but *only* in certain contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
>>> import re
>>> a = 'Beautiful. is. better5-than ugly'
>>> re.findall("\w+[.-]?|\s+", a)
['Beautiful.', ' ', 'is.', ' ', 'better5-', 'than', ' ', 'ugly']
```

- `\w+[.-]?` matches words with an optional dot or hyphen at the end.
- `\s+` matches whitespace.
- `|` makes sure we capture either of the above.

Answer (score 2):

Since we want our delimiters to be part of our result, we should keep them so, I used both "lookbehind" and "lookahead" assertions in the regex. You can read about them in the [`re` module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re
a = 'Beautiful. is. better5-than ugly'
print(re.split(r'(?<=[-. ])|(?= )', a))
```

Additional note: with "lookbehind" assertion I could achieve almost the same result, but for the last word "than " I need to include a "lookahead" assertion to my regex pattern (I mean `|(?= )`) to split that space too.